# java fileUpload multiparts return null

Tags: jsp, apache-commons-fileupload

I can not get file name on my code. Basically it writes upload is successful in result page but it doesnt show file name and doesnt upload to ftp server. And it saves null in database. Could anyone help me on it pls? Here is all the codes:

UserDao.java :

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.MultipartConfig;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

@WebServlet(name = "UserDao", urlPatterns = {"/UserDao"})
@MultipartConfig()

public class UserDao extends HttpServlet {

private final String UPLOAD_DIRECTORY = "/upload";

/**
 * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code>
 * methods.
 *
 * @param request servlet request
 * @param response servlet response
 * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
 * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
 */
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
String x = "";
            if (ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request)) {
                try {
//                x += request;
                    List<FileItem> multiparts = new ServletFileUpload(
                            new DiskFileItemFactory()).parseRequest(request);
                    //File uploaded successfully

                    for (FileItem item : multiparts) {
                        String fileName = item.getName();
                        File file = new File(UPLOAD_DIRECTORY + File.separator + fileName);
                        item.write(file);
                        x += fileName + " @@ ";
                    }
                    request.setAttribute("message", "File Uploaded Successfully: " + UPLOAD_DIRECTORY + File.separator + x);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    request.setAttribute("message", "File Upload Failed due to " + ex);
                }
            } else {
                request.setAttribute("message",
                        "Sorry this Servlet only handles file upload request");
            }
        UsersPojo users = new UsersPojo();
            users.setId(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("idx")));
            users.setEmail(request.getParameter("email"));
            users.setFirstname(request.getParameter("first_name"));
            users.setLastname(request.getParameter("last_name"));
            users.setPhone("");
            users.setCity(request.getParameter("city"));
            users.setCountry(request.getParameter("country"));
            users.setJob_title(request.getParameter("job_title"));
            users.setCompany(request.getParameter("company"));
            users.setFollow(request.getParameter("follow"));
            users.setPicture(request.getParameter("picture"));
            users.setLogo(request.getParameter("logo"));
            UserDB.updateUser(users);
   request.getRequestDispatcher("/results.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

welcome.jsp:

```
<form method="post" action="UserDao" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                        <div class="col-sm-7" >
                                            <input type="hidden" id="idx" name="idx" value="<%=id%>">
                                            <input type="hidden" id="email" name="email" value="<%=up.getEmail()%>">
                                            <input type="hidden" id="follow" name="follow" value="<%=up.getFollow()%>">
                                            <div class=" col-sm-12">
                                                <div class="form-group margin15">
                                                    <label for="first_name">First name<strong style="color: #f00">*</strong></label>
                                                    <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" value="<%=up.getFirstname()%>" class="form-control" required>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class=" col-sm-12">
                                                <div class="form-group margin15">
                                                    <label for="last_name">Last name<strong style="color: #f00">*</strong></label>
                                                    <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" value="<%=up.getLastname()%>" class="form-control" required>
                                                    <p style="font-size: small;">*You wish to hide your last name:  write only the first letter</p>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class=" col-sm-12">
                                                <div class="form-group margin15">
                                                    <label for="city">City<strong style="color: #f00">*</strong></label>
                                                    <input type="text" name="city" id="city" value="<%=up.getCity()%>" class="form-control" required>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class=" col-sm-12">
                                                <div class="form-group margin15">
                                                    <label for="country">Country<strong style="color: #f00">*</strong></label>
                                                    <input type="text" name="country" id="country" value="<%=up.getCountry()%>" class="form-control" required>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class=" col-sm-12">
                                                <div class="form-group margin15 topmargin30">
                                                    <label for="job_title">Your job title<strong style="color: #f00">*</strong></label>
                                                    <input type="text" name="job_title" id="job_title" value="<%=up.getJob_title()%>" class="form-control" required>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class=" col-sm-12">
                                                <div class="form-group margin15">
                                                    <label for="company">Your company<strong style="color: #f00">*</strong></label>
                                                    <input type="text" name="company" id="company" value="<%=up.getCompany()%>" class="form-control" required>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-sm-12" style="margin-top: 20px;color: #f00; font-size: 20px"><strong style="color: #f00; font-size: 23px">*</strong> Required</div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-5" style="margin-top:10px">
                                            <div class="paddingprof widget">
                                                <div class="user-photo" style="padding: 0px; ">
                                                    <img src="assets/img/capture2.png" alt="User Photo" class="" style="border-radius: 0px">
                                                </div>
                                                <!-- /.user-photo -->
                                                <div class="background-white">
                                                    <h4 style="text-align: center">Upload your photo</h4>
                                                    <input type="file" name="picture" id="picture">
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <!-- /.widget -->
                                            <!--                                    <div class="paddingprof widget">
                                                                                   <div class="user-photo"  style="padding: 0px;">
                                                                                      <img src="assets/img/airbus.png" alt="User Photo" style="border-radius: 0px">
                                                                                   </div>
                                                                                   <div class="background-white">
                                                                                      <h4 style="text-align: center">Upload your logo</h4>
                                                                                      <input type="file" name="logo" id="logo" >
                                                                                   </div>
                                                                                </div>-->
                                            <!-- /.widget -->
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="col-sm-12" style="text-align: center">
                                            <button type="submit" name="btnEditComp" id="btnEditComp" class="btn1 btn btn-lg btn-primary" style="font-size: 23px;padding-right: 35px;padding-left: 35px;" >
                                                Save
                                            </button>
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
```

results.jsp :

```
<h3>${requestScope["message"]}</h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the null check at least:

```
if (fileName != null) {
    File file = new File(UPLOAD_DIRECTORY + File.separator + fileName);
    item.write(file);
    x += fileName + " @@ ";
}
```

The variable `multiparts` includes `DiskFileItem` instances of other fields, for example, `idx`, `email`, `first_name`, ... and they don't have a file name.

Comment: The problem is filename brings nothing at all. Because of it I added " @@ " stuff to check if something exist in there or not. And I didnt see @@ sign in outputs

Comment: Hmm? I can see `File Uploaded Successfully: /upload/sample_users.xml @@` in results.jsp if I upload `sample_users.xml`. What message did you see?

Comment: I see just `File Uploaded Successfully: /upload/`

Answer (score 0):

The following line returns all the items of your multipart form :

```
List<FileItem> multiparts = new ServletFileUpload(
                            new DiskFileItemFactory()).parseRequest(request);
```

Therefore, when you are processing the uploaded file you need to exclude the rest of the form items :

```
                for (FileItem item : multiparts) {
                    if (!item.isFormField()) {
                       String fileName = item.getName();
                       File file = new File(UPLOAD_DIRECTORY + File.separator + fileName);
                       item.write(file);
                       x += fileName + " @@ ";
                    }
                 }
```

Comment: It is not helped